# <rowExpansion> evaluated during JSF phases

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, rowexpansion

I have a datatable using rowExpansion.
When the page is loaded, the rowExpansion is not evaluated, which is fine.
When the paginator is used to show the next results or if a submission is done -  the rowExpansion evaluation is triggered.

Here is a XHTML example :

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable var="data" value="#{bean.dataList}" paginator="true">
        <p:column headerText="Details">
            <p:rowToggler />
        </p:column>
        <p:rowExpansion>
            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty data.detail}">
                <ui:include src="dataDetail.xhtml" />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </p:rowExpansion>
    </p:dataTable>
    <h:commandLink id="addData" value="Add data" action="#{bean.addData}" />
</h:form>
```

I've profiled this flow using visualVM, and used the debugger, to discover that the `data.getDetail()` method was called during the following JSF phases :  (`ApplyRequestValuesPhase`, `ProcessValidationsPhase`, `UpdateModelValuesPhase`), when the paginator was used.

I've come to the deduction that the rowExpansion is part of the view, and is evaluated as a normal component.

Would you mind telling me if it is the expected behaviour for rowExpansion ?

Is there a correct way to prevent the evaluation of the rowExpansion content when using the paginator ?

Thanks for your answers.

NB : I'm using PrimeFaces 5.2.

Comment: Good debugging. Please try 5.3 or 6.0 or 6.1 or 6.2 just for this issue to see if it makes a difference. If it is different in a newer version it was a bug.

Comment: I've tried 5.3 but without any change. I've also taken a peek at PrimeFaces sources (5.2 and also 6.2 to check if any difference) to found some clues about why the `RowExpansion` element is processed. It seems to be part of the view, except if not rendered like any other component.